# How to get height and width of dynamically designed user control while added in wpf canvas control?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Hello I am developing one wpf application. I am adding object of myUserControl in canvas. i need height and with of added usercontrol. Now problem is that user control is design dynamically, i am creating grid and adding row and column according to configured by user, and i am giving auto in height and width. so i am not getting actual height and width of user control while adding it in canvas.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All UI elements derived from `FrameworkElement` have the [`ActualWidth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualwidth.aspx) and [`ActualHeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualheight.aspx) properties.

Comment: When i am adding control in canvas it is null. but once object is added in canvas then if i find usercontrol by name and check i got ActualHeight and Width, but i need it when control is actually added in canvas.

Comment: I think you can force size calculation by doing a call to UpdateLayout() on your user control.